# Как узнать процентное соотношение прохождения по ветке дерева Nested Sets?

Tags: php, nested-sets

Есть дерево вопросов и ответов.
При прохождении опросника, нужно показывать прогресс бар, в процентном соотношении.
Получить количество узлов вверх, очень просто, и соответственно узнать сколько узлов мы прошли по дереву.
Но как высчитать процент для прогресс бара, если мы незнаем, по какой ветке дерева пойдет пользователь?